# Google Chrome datepicker events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need to be notified when a user selects a new date from the native datepicker control in Google Chrome.

You need to be on Google Chrome 20+ to see the native datepicker control.

Some users were suggesting that in iOS5 the `onBlur` event is fired, but that does not seem to be the case with Chrome.

Comment: Both `onchange` and `onblur` seems to fire on the desktop/Windows Chrome? http://jsfiddle.net/6gxN2/ Is this specifically in a tablet/phone interface?

Comment: @JaredFarrish this is on Windows. onchange and onblur fire when the input loses focus. If I select a new value from the date picker , they are not fired until the focus is removed from the date input.

Comment: So you want to know when the date picker widget closes (but the field doesn't necessarily blur/change)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish correct. If chrome fires a "widget close" event it would be perfect. I would like to know when the value in the input has changed. The issue is that neither keyup, keydown or keypress are getting triggered. The only solution i see is attaching a timer function that checks if the input value has been modified.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I mocked up: http://jsfiddle.net/6gxN2/1/ I don't know what the events are for the `date` input type.

Comment: It's possible `oninput` might work: http://jsfiddle.net/6gxN2/2/ Although note, this looks like it fires during `window.onload` as well.

Comment: That describes what you're looking for, doesn't it? The in-between? I can't see the native datepicker has it's own events to intercept, event `click` doesn't fire when you're in the datepicker context (which is how I ended up finding the `oninput` event).

Comment: I can't find the native datepicker has any event handlers at the moment, but that might change. Between `onclick` and `oninput`, this more or less gives the same effect. It would be nice to have a way to handle this. Are you doing a validation check? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am posting the values with AJAX when they change. Since the input event is fired when we type as well, i need to ensure that the user is not still typing the date (verify that the current value is a valid date, not 11/0 )

Comment: That sounds like typical `onchange` requirement.

Comment: Then you need to listen for `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` in order to prevent the user from typing in the date, but why would you do that? That's a usability issue. `type="date"` and still very new and not supported by many browsers and versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome 24 fires the change event when the date has changed, even if the focus has not been moved from the textbox.

The change event seems to fire even if the date is manually changed by the user.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Chrome 20.0.1132.57 on a Windows machine and the `oninput` event seems to work quite well for this. I noticed that Jared commented that this event fires during `window.onload`, but I haven't been able to reproduce that (hopefully I'm not missing something obvious there).

To test it I just set up a page with a `form` element and an `input` of type `date` and wrote an inline event handler for `oninput` like so:

```
<form>
  <input type="date" id="theDate" oninput="alert('oninput event fired');" />
</form>
```

Every time I click on a date, the today button, or the clear button (and *only* if the date changes with this click) I am alerted that the event has fired. This event does not fire when changing the current month with any of the controls at the top of the date picker.

Here's a working demo on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ihisis/2/edit). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried using only the `addEventListner`:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var d = document.getElementById('date');

    d.addEventListener('input', function(e){
        alert(d.value);
    });
};​
```

And it works that way. So maybe you are using too many functions which are conflicting each